# The semantic use of "either" in the following phrase:

Tags: either-or

I was wondering if any of you would be able to give me some clarification on what you take the intention of the final phrase below to be:

> The term ‘mental decolonization’ has been associated with Frantz Fanon and
>   Kwame Nkrumah alike. What does EITHER of these thinkers understand by this
>   term and how does EITHER think mental colonization can be overcome?
>
> Note: please focus on EITHER ONE of these theorists in your answer

Does this mean that the recipient is supposed to focus their answer on *both* theorists, or only *one* theorist?

Thank you in advance for your help with this issue. I find it quite embarrassing that as a native speaker I cannot myself figure out what the intention is.

edit: It would seem that the general consensus is that the author of the question intended focus on only one theorist. However, if you feel that there is cause to disagree with this, please feel free to share your views.

Comment: The assignment asks you to choose one. *Either* means one, and you may select which one. If you address their joint understanding together, or each one as an individual, you will lose points for disregarding the question.

Comment: In that passage, I would assume that you only have write about a single person. However, the author is guilty of not being explicit and of causing possible confusion. It could all have been avoided by using *"Note: please focus on **ONLY ONE** of these theorists in your answer.* The use of the word *focus* also implies a narrowing of attention. After all, it would be somewhat silly to say *focus on both* when there are only two to start with. If **both** had been meant, I assume the wording would have been something like ***discuss*** *both*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin It's not true that *either* always means only one and not the other.  Although it commonly does, sometimes the two things do not need to be exclusive of each other. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/either): *plays **either** instrument well.* In that context, it means plays **both** instruments well. (Take your pick, either is played well.) That's why although we can *assume* exclusivity here, it's not necessarily how it's supposed to be taken.

Comment: 'Either' in the unusual usage you mention means 'X, yes; Y, yes – but not both at the same time'. This can't apply to OP's example.

Comment: @JasonBassford - The word either shows up three times in this problem.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's not unusual usage at all. That's just one of several examples used in Merriam-Webster's definition of the word. In fact, it's the *first* sense of the word that's listed—which is equated with *each*.

Comment: @JasonBassford this is why I'm so confused, as to me, in this particular instance, 'either' can well mean 'both'.

Comment: Yes. Although, as I've said, I *assume* that what was meant was *pick **only** one*, there is still a bit of doubt. Even if you say *pick **either** one*, that does not necessarily mean *pick either one **and** only one.* Some students choose to do extra work. Although asked to write about only one thing, they'll write about two or more things.Those are the typically the eager students who enjoy what they're writing about. Many teachers don't **prohibit** the ability to provide more than the minimum required. These instructions don't make that explicitly clear either.

Comment: I just edited your question to put the third instance of *either* in all caps. It wasn't until I glanced back at an earlier comment of yours that I realized it was used three times. That just makes the chosen wording more awkward. It should really be *do they* in that first paragraph, and then *ONLY ONE* in the follow-up note. Assuming the likely interpretation is correct.

Comment: @JasonBassford Unfortunately, in this case, I cannot afford to pick the wrong interpretation, as given the nature of the question, I would not be answering it correctly. However, given your (and others') understanding of it, I certianly feel more confident that I will be correct in only writing about one theorist. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: It's definitely ambiguous.

Comment: @ArmelFrançois If it's matter of a grade, or some other information whose answer is essential, you should just ask about the intended instructions. Our guesses (however well informed) are still just guesses. We might be wrong.

Comment: @JasonBassford My university is currently closed, so I am left to rely upon democratic means. But your advice is nonetheless appreciated.

Comment: @JasonBassford The usage you give 'he can play either instrument well' is the unusual one; it's conflated with the 'both at the same time' (_on either side_) (which is a fixed expression) usage in M-W. I'll leave you to look at say 1000 Google hits for 'either' to see how frequently the 'both, but not at the same time' sense occurs; I think we could both guess the answer to within 1%.

Comment: It might have been ambiguous without the author's qualification "please focus on EITHER **ONE** of these theorists". In my world "either" never means "both". It means "one of". The phrase "on either side" means "choose one side." There is another way of saying "both sides" too - "each side."

Answer (score -3):

OED:

**Either**:

> II. One or other of the two.
>
> absolute adjective [used] as a pronoun.
>
> 1849   Macaulay Hist. Eng. I. 164   *Whatever was ridiculous or odious in either increased the scorn and aversion which the multitude felt for both.*

Compare with "both" in the quotation above.

Comment: Well that would seem to miss out what is detailed by the OED in definition I.

Comment: I suggest you understand that "either" has several functions. I have given you the one that is relevant to the quote you gave. Definition 1 in the OED refers to "either" used as an attributive adjective "1819   Scott Ivanhoe I. iii. 47   *There was a huge fire-place at either end of the hall,* If you have a problem with the OED, you may wish to write.